# Java .split() by character with spaces in string

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to read a line from a text file in java. I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` exception.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line = "";
    int count = 0;
    while (kb.hasNext()) {
        line = kb.next();
        String[] temp = line.split("#");
        System.out.println(temp[1]);
        Wedding tempWed = new Wedding(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], Integer.parseInt(temp[4]));
        test[count] = tempWed;
        count++;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

}
```

This is the line in the textfile:
`Chiquita Sanford#Magee Sosa#2016-11-05#Garden#84`

I need to split by the "#", and this partly works. 
Java throws the exception when I try to access the element at position 1.
I think this is because there is a space between the first name and the surname, because when I `System.out.println(temp[0])` it displays "Chiquita" and not "Chiquita Sanford".

Does Java have some restriction on splitting when there are multiple words in the first array index.

Comment: Change `kb.next()` to `kb.nextLine()`, and change `kb.hasNext()` to `kb.hasNextLine()`.

Comment: Better yet, don't use `Scanner`, since it is slow. Use `BufferedReader` and its `readLine()` method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) method to read the full line. [next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) will read until the first token ("Chiquita" in your case because its followed by a space character and is interpreted as a delimiter). So change this line:

```
line = kb.next();
```

with this:

```
line = kb.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you! My coffee high has come to a plateau. Knew we were making a silly mistake!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `kb.next()` that will return the next word not the next line, for this use `kb.nextLine()` similar issue with `kb.hasNext()` needs to be `kb.hasNextLine()`